# Managing icon PNG files in Android App

Tags: android, android-resources

I am developing an application which creates menu with each menu item having its own icon. I have too many PNG files for each menu item. In future i will be updating menu items from WebService which will add to these png files.

What is the most efficient way to store this data(png files). I don't want to keep it in drawable folder as I can't update contents of drawable folder after i have shipped my app. If i am storing it on External Memory, How do i achieve that? Where exactly should i copy these png files and use them as resources in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them as BLOBs in sqLite.

Comment: it will make database slow, there are going to be categories and then an image for items within categories.

Comment: which database Hakeem? Store the image in a separate database with a GUID.  Reference the guid. problem solved.  an SQLite is nothing but a file anyway.

Comment: + how do you know it will make it slow anyway?  Did you examine the query plan for sqLite?

Comment: i have a sqlitedatabse, keeping all the information about these items. i want to store references of images in db, not the whole image as blob.

Comment: not examined, i am searching around and its recommended to keep paths to images instead of storing them in blob.

Comment: This forum is not about what you WANT.  Its about what will or will not work.

Comment: So what, you have one opinion that says yah and another that says nay. Whoever nixed the db option obviously did not have a plan or you would just be following that.

Comment: don't you think it would cause read write overhead? png files are static data

Comment: test it and see.  There is a lot of work on sqLite for optimization.

Comment: perhaps it would. I think with the right permissions you can write it to memory.

Comment: actually i don't want to just keep doing something that works and after sometime i realize that it wont fit in as expected. i am asking because I DON'T KNOW implications of both ways !

i will have to sync my data from a web server in future. i planned to keep these png files in drawable folder. now i have 2 ways of handling this, 1) keep them in phone memory and save references in db 2) store them as blob.

Comment: Thats about it. Perhaps you could create a single sprite sheet for some of the images. That might help.

Comment: i think storing in blob is the most simplest thing, i should give it a try first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write to private space assigned to your app using this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int) method and read back with it's sibling.

```
InputStream is = your input stream
OutputStream os = mContext.openFileOutput("image.png",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Utils.copyStream(is,os);  //Your own steam copy here

is.close;
os.close;
```

Comment: is it required to store all data first time when i allocate this space to my app? can't i have this space at compile time?

Comment: No the best way to do this is have all your built in icons in your assets folder and copy them into this location on first run. Or you could just wrap the way you load the files so that first you try opening `mContext.openFileInput(...)` and if that fails try opening it out of your assets with `mContext.getAssets().open(...)`